# how to replace the substrings in a string

Tags: php, string

I am searching for a function in PHP to replace the substrings in a string.

Input string is

```
<a href="#">Test Link1</a><p class="more">something</p><a href="#">Test Link2</a> <p>some more things</p>
```

and output string is

```
&nbsp;<p class="more">something</p>&nbsp; <p>some more things</p>
```

Here, 'Test Link' caption is dynamic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp

```
$str = '<a href="#">Test Link</a><p class="more">something</p><a href="#">Test Link</a> <p>some more things</p>';
echo preg_replace('/<a.*?<\/a>/is', '&nbsp;', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '<a href="#">Test Link</a><p class="more">something</p><a href="#">Test Link</a> <p>some more things</p>';
$output = preg_replace('!<a href="#">(.*?)</a>!', '', $str);
```

Comment: 'Test Link' caption is dynamic.

Comment: I have changed to preg_replace.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [php.net](http://php.net) php.net - in this specific case I searched for replace
on that site and found a lot of useful references.

[Search ex.](https://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=replace&scope=quickref)

/Anders